npm start for parcel bundling returns * No entries found
I am currently doing the JavaScript Simplified course on https://courses.webdevsimplified.com/ and he is teaching how to use parcel to bundle a html file. But I can't get it to work properly.
And he says that after changing:
"scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" }
to
"scripts": { "start": "parcel index.html" } 
inside the package.json file, I should run npm start on the terminal, but when I do that I get returned:
Server running at http://localhost:xxxx

No entries found.


Where exactly is your index.html located and from where are you executing this command. The given error indicates that parcel cannot find or correctly handle the index.html
